# Cordova list all files from application directory (WWW)

Tags: html, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using `Cordova 4.2.0` with plugins File and media. I have some mp3 files in audio folder inside `www` directory. I am able to play files through media plugin using path `cordova.file.applicationDirectory+"www/audio/01.mp3"` and  trying to get all available files list using `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` but unable to do so. Please see below code always goes to fail function.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory+'/www/audio', 
    function(dirEntry){
        alert('in');
    }, 
    fail
);
```

Please guide me the best way.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use this function to get all available files in www/audio/ folder

```
function listDir(path){
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
    function (fileSystem) {
      var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
      reader.readEntries(
        function (entries) {
          console.log(entries);
        },
        function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
//example: list of www/audio/ folder in cordova/ionic app.
listDir(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/audio/");
```

Comment: why are these functions not available in documentation?

Comment: This function use just html5 features, except for "cordova.file.applicationDirectory" (Documentation is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/)

Comment: Great ! I was looking at cordova plugin API for file transfer.

Comment: The docs is here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Comment: I get 0 results when listing `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/`  does this have to do with Android permissions?

Comment: Yes, look around android persmission. I don't know if you have permission to read this volume.

Comment: Please see this issue if you are having trouble. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/426