# how to access all files from any one folder in mobile file manager in ionic 1

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to make an app to list images like photo gallery in android.
To do that, I used ngCordova camera plugin or Cordova image picker plugin.
The plugins, however, need one-by-one image selection to get results by using touch event on photo library; plus, the limit option for the result. That is far from what I am going to.
I am wondering how to retrieve all images rather than manual selection.
Could you tell me how to approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cordova-file is what you are looking for.

You can use this function to get all available files in a folder:

```
function listDir(path){
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
    function (fileSystem) {
      var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
      reader.readEntries(
        function (entries) {
          console.log(entries);
        },
        function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
//example: list of www/ folder in cordova/ionic app.
listDir(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "directory/path");
```

see this also: [Cordova list all files from application directory (WWW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937878/cordova-list-all-files-from-application-directory-www)

Comment: i don't want our app directory.but it's done with "cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"Foldername/"..thank u .thank u so much