# How to read files of my application in ionic / cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugin-file

I'm trying to simply read the files under `src/assets/data` (I've created the `data` directory with some text files under it).

I've tried many ways without success:

```typescript
this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl("/assets/data") // as well tested with "/www/assets/data" and "/www/assets/data/", with or without the front "/", as well with all those solutions with `this.file.applicationDirectory +` in front of the string
  .then(directoryEntry => {
    directoryEntry.createReader().readEntries(function (entries: Entry[]) {
      for (let entry of entries) {
        console.log(entry);
      }
    })
  });
```

and

```typescript
this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(this.file.applicationDirectory+"assets/data/")
```

as well as what suggested [another reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32348887/535203)

```typescript
(<any>window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.file.applicationDirectory + "www/assets/data/",
  function (fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.createReader().readEntries(function (entries: Entry[]) {
      for (let entry of entries) {
        console.log(entry);
      }
    })
  },
  function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
);
```

For all those solutions I always end with te following error: "`A URI supplied to the API was malformed, or the resulting Data URL has exceeded the URL length limitations for Data URLs.`"

I'm running cordova with `ionic cordova run browser --port=8000` and `this.file.applicationDirectory` is equal to `http://localhost:8000/`

Does someone know how to do this simple thing? Or should I move my `data` folder in another place and use another API to simply read my local application files?

I'm using the following dependencies versions (among others) in my `package.json`:

```
"@angular/core": "5.0.3",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.3",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-ionic": "3.0.0",
"cordova-browser": "~5.0.3"
```

Comment: use File Plugin, More details https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/

Comment: This is what I tested @kishore.k.vaishnav, see my `package.json` which integrates `@ionic-native/file` & `cordova-plugin-file`.

Answer (score 0):

`applicationDirectory` is not supported in browser platform, so it won't work there, you have to test in one of the supported platforms. (iOS, Android, Windows, OSX)